# Selecting fields to create query in access, automatically adds asterisk * to the fields selected. It shows up in the SQL view, but not query design

Tags: sql, ms-access

Query design in MS Access:

[image: 1]

SQL view in MS Access:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an application setting.

File > Options > Object Designers > Query design > uncheck "Output all fields"

Comment: thanks you figured it out faster and your answer is clear

Answer (score 0):

Turn off output all fields in the property sheet of query properties. it is on yes by default. So to turn it off permanently go to:

file at the upper right hand of the ribbon, click it,  then at the bottom, options, then to object designers, then query designers, then uncheck the box> out put all fields